# SQL Server Query Performance with Timestamp and variable

Tags: sql-server, performance, timestamp

I have a simple SQL query to count the number of telemetry records by clients within the last 24 hours.

With an index on TimeStamp, the following query runs in less than 1 seconds for about 10k rows

```
select MachineName,count(Message) from Telemetry where TimeStamp between DATEADD(HOUR,-24, getutcdate()) and getutcdate() group by MachineName
```

However, when I tried to making the hard-coded -24 configurable and added a variable, it took more than 5 min for the query to get executed.

```
DECLARE @cutoff int; SET @cutoff = 24

select MachineName,count(Message) from Telemetry where TimeStamp between DATEADD(HOUR, -1*@cutoff, getutcdate()) and getutcdate() group by MachineName
```

Is there any specific reason for the significant decrease of performance? What's the best way of adding a variable without impacting performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you also have an index on MachineName - or that SQL is deciding that since it needs to group by MachineName, that would be a better way to access the records.

Updating statistics as suggested by AngularRat is a good start - but SQL often maintains those automatically.  (In fact, the good performance when SQL knows the 24 hour interval *in advance* is evidence that the statistics are good...but when SQL doesn't know the size of the BETWEEN in advance, then it thinks other approaches might be a better idea).

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE Telemetry  ( machineName sysname, message varchar(88), [timestamp] timestamp)
CREATE INDEX Telemetry_TS ON Telemetry([timestamp]);
```

First, try the `OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR ( @cutoff = 24 ));` clause to let SQL know how to approach the query, and if that is insufficient then try  `WITH (Index( Telemetry_TS))`.  Using the INDEX hint is less desirable.

```
DECLARE @cutoff int = 24;
select MachineName,count(Message) 
from Telemetry  -- WITH (Index( Telemetry_TS))
where TimeStamp between DATEADD(HOUR, -1*@cutoff, getutcdate()) and getutcdate() 
group by MachineName
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR ( @cutoff = 24 ));
```

Comment: Yes, there is another index on MachineName. I tried adding the OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR ( @cutoff = 24 )) clause, works perfectly! I guess SQL server is picking a wrong execution plan without specifying the value using the option clause.

Comment: Not the *wrong* plan, just not the plan for which you hoped.  SQL has optimization rules it applies to guess the 'selectivity' of each query predicate ...how many rows will 'hit' a BETWEEN -vs- and EQUAL -vs- a GREATER THAN (>).   With an unknown value, SQL assumed MANY ROWS would match the BETWEEN - the hint gives it advance knowledge.  REF http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2011/01/25/query_5f00_tuning_5f00_key_5f00_terms.aspx

Comment: Agreed. "Wrong" might not be the best way to describe it here. The option clause provides a hint that I'm only looking for a very limited range of data, which is how I would like the query to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter should actually work, but you MIGHT be seeing an issue where the database is using out of date statistics for the query plan.  I'd try updating statistics for the table you are quering.  Something like:

```
UPDATE STATISTICS TableName;
```

Additionally, if your code is running from within a stored procedure, you might want to recompile the procedure.  Something like:

```
EXEC sp_recompile N'ProcedureName';
```

A lot of times when I have a query that seems like it should run a lot faster but isn't, it's a statistic/query plan out of date issue.

References:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The query is manually executed now rather than in a stored procedure. I tried UPDATE STATISTICS, didn't seems to improve the performance a lot.